# generated url by paginator is not right in ZF2

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2

I come across an issue with ZF2 Paginating. The generate url by paginator is not correct. Could anyone help point wrong place in my configuration?  I just made small change for example in page: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html

Below is my change:  module.config.php:

```
    'routes' => array(
        'shop' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/shop',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Shop\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(

                'paginator' => array(
                     'type' => 'segment',
                     'options' => array(
                         'route' => '/index/list[/page/:page]',
                         'defaults' => array(
                              'page' => 1,
                           ),
                      ),
                  ),

                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
          ....
         'template_map' => array(
           ...                 
         'index/page' => __DIR__ . '/../view/shop/index/page.phtml',
        ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

In the IndexController:

```
public function listAction(){
    $array =  array(
             0 => array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'samsonasik'),
             .......
     );
    $paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator(new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter($array));

    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page'));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(1);
    $vm = new ViewModel();
    $vm->setVariable('paginator', $paginator);
    return $vm;
}
```

For the list.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,
                                'Sliding',
                                'index/page', array('route' => 'shop/paginator')); ?>
```

The script type index/pgae is mapped to page.phtml. I tried all three example controls in: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#example-pagination-controls and changes arguments of $this->url() but all fail. For example, for search pagination, I change all:

```
$this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->previous));
```

to

```
$this->url($this->route, array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'list','page' => $page));
```

For page:HOST/shop/index/list, all href of 2,3..and next in pagination control point to 
      HOST/shop/index/list/page/2         HOST/shop/index/list/page/3
This is what I expected, but this url matches shop/default instead of shop/paginator

Now the problem become simple:
how to write shop/paginator router so that url HOST/shop/index/list/page/2 can be matched:

```
                'paginator' => array(
                     'type' => 'segment',
                     'options' => array(
                         'route' => '/index/list[/page/:page]',
                         'defaults' => array(
                              'page' => 1,
                           ),
                      ),
                  ),

                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

Comment: In list.phtml you supply a router, in the page.phtml you use a route. Mind the different spelling. Is this a typo in this question or in your code as well?

Comment: Thanks @Jurian, It is type error.... After fix typo error.. The linked url becomes:  HOST/shop/index/list/2. Yet, this url does not match shop/paginator router.. The result shows it only matches shop/default router. What's wrong it? Thanks..

Comment: I solved this issue in another solution.. That is: add hierarchy child route